# How to disable Ligatures/Diacritics functionality in mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

I generate PDFs with MPDF 8.1.1. These PDF include email addresses. But it looks like the "Combining Diacritics" functionality or the "Ligatures" of the font rendering destroys some of them. I provide UTF8 encoded text.

For example, if the address contains `ffl`, it replaces this by a glyph `ﬄ` and turns the email address invalid.

I tried to instantiate mPDF with *allow_charset_conversion=false* like this

```
$pdf = new Mpdf\Mpdf([
  'PDFA' => true,
  'PDFAauto' => true,
  'allow_charset_conversion' => false
]);
```

But it continues to destroy emails.

What is the correct way to disable that "Combining Diacritics" functionality or "Ligatures" replacement?

Comment: I think you are barking up the wrong tree here with "Combining Diacritics" - those would be stuff like accents, dots over umlauts, tilde etc. What you are dealing with, are _ligatures_, https://practicaltypography.com/ligatures-in-programming-fonts-hell-no.html Those are a feature of the font, so if mpdf doesn't offer any explicit option to not use them, maybe try a different font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mPDF documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/opentype-layout-otl.html#examples) gives this CSS style to disable ligatures:

```css
/* disable common ligatures, usually on by default */
.noligs { font-feature-settings: "liga" 0; }
```

Alternatively you can use [`'useOTL' => 0`](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/opentype-layout-otl.html#how-to-use-otl-in-mpdf) to disable all OTL features on a font.

Comment: Thanks! The "useOTL" setting worked for me.